# how do I abort active downloads of Ubuntu 22.04.iso files

Tags: firefox

I have 5 active downloads of the same 22.04.iso file going on. The downloads window didn't show at all. I confirmed as I closed my browser that I wanted to cancel the downloads. I deleted the (part) files and have rebooted a few times but every time I open my browser the files appear active in Downloads folder again.

Answer (score 1):

You have three options in Firefox.

1. Let the downloads complete.
2. Cancel the downloads using the Downloads button along the top bar

   [image]
3. Cancel the downloads using the Downloads window in your settings menu

   [image]